# How to find memory usage of a program in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memory

I have some stuff to do and for that I need to find memory usage of a program in Haskell, but I dont know how. Any ideas ? My version of GHC is 7.10.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one easy way is to compile with `-rtsopts`

```
ghc -O2 -rtsopts Test.hs -o test
```

and then run it with

```
./test +RTS -s
```

---

if you need actual profiling you can compile with `-prof` and run with `-p` - this will produce a `.prof` file you can then examine

(see [profiling user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html))